# Split string of a webview Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview which picks a bit of html from a server. In the Webview there are two ints which are  passed by a % "token". I use integer.toString to make it visible as text which works perfectly. Now in my HTML i have twice a % token, the first is meant to become the oldPrice and the second one is to become the newPrice.

However both become the oldPrice because it's exactly the same reference. Is there a way to say in Android(Java), the first % must become oldPrice and the second % must become newPrice?

Can somebody help me in the right path?

Thanks in advance,
Zakaria

The HTML :

    
        Tegen 
            %d punten 
            %@ 
            %.2f euro voor 
            %.2f euro.

The Java Code :

```
String taglineText = mStrings.getString(ApplicationStrings.ConfigNames.Redeem.REWARD_POINTS_WITH_PRICE).replace("%d", Integer.toString(item.shizzleP)).replace("%@", item.tagline).replace("%.2f",Integer.toString(item.oldPrice)).replace("%.2f", Integer.toString(item.newPrice));
```

P.S : I am talking about the third % and the fourth % (%.2f)

Comment: this is weird. it looks like a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax format string, but %@ is not a pattern. I would replace that %@ with a %s, then use String.format.

Comment: as a further argument, `%.2f` indicates a number with 2 decimals, which you replace with an integer. This is probably not the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is an easy workaround:

```
String taglineText = mStrings.getString(ApplicationStrings.ConfigNames.Redeem.REWARD_POINTS_WITH_PRICE).replace("%d", Integer.toString(item.shizzleP)).replace("%@", item.tagline).replaceFirst("%\\.2f",Integer.toString(item.oldPrice)).replaceFirst("%\\.2f", Integer.toString(item.newPrice));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks !! Can you explain me the working of it?

Comment: yes dude, replaceFirst method replaces the first occurence of the first argument but it takes a regex in the form of a string that is why i used "%\\.2f" instead of "%.2f", now since the first pattern has been replaced, we call the method again and it replaces the second pattern considering it as the first and we get the desired output, was i clear?

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, your string is a [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), except for the `@`, which should probably be an `s`. I would do:

```
String taglineText = String.format(
    mStrings.getString(KEY).replace("%@", "%s"), 
    item.shizzleP, item.tagline, item.oldPrice, item.newPrice);
```